# how to make plus-sign like table of 2 rows and 2 columns using bootstrap or css? (as shown in image-link)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]

I want a plus sign like table of two rows and two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fontawesome` icons??? Read their documentation about how to use it: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css

There is a plug icon from `fontawesome` - `<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>`:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus?style=solid

Answer (score 0):

```css
table,
tr,
td {
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 20px;
}

td {
  border-top-style: solid !important;
  border-left-style: solid !important;
  border-right-style: solid !important;
  border-bottom-style: solid !important;
}

td.TopLeft {
  border-top-style: none !important;
  border-left-style: none !important;
}

td.TopRight {
  border-top-style: none !important;
  border-right-style: none !important;
}

td.BottomLeft {
  border-Bottom-style: none !important;
  border-left-style: none !important;
}

td.BottomRight {
  border-bottom-style: none !important;
  border-Right-style: none !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="TopLeft"></td>
    <td class="TopRight"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="BottomLeft"></td>
    <td class="BottomRight"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```